# How to generate sysID with multiple variables from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a sysID for entries in my code. I have tried to generate it successfully but in my code, I have used many if else conditions which took almost 150 lines of code. But I want to generate it in fewer lines of code.

I am using something like:

```
$companyletter = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
$dbletter = array('aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah', 'ai', 'aj', 'ak', 'al', 'am', 'an', 'ao', 'ap', 'aq', 'ar', 'as', 'at', 'au', 'av', 'aw', 'ax', 'ay', 'az');
$comapnyID = mb_substr('COMPANY', 0, 2);
$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id FROM `panel_product` WHERE `post_company` LIKE '%".$_GET['company']."%'");
            $sql->execute();
            $companyCount = $sql->rowCount();
            if ($companyCount < 10) {
                $companyCount = '0'.($companyCount+1);
            } else {
                $companyCount = ($companyCount+1);
            }
$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id FROM `panel_product`");
            $sql->execute();
            $dbCount = $sql->rowCount();
            if ($dbCount < 10) {
                $dbCount = '00'.($dbCount+1);
            } else if ($dbCount < 100) {
                $dbCount = '0'.($dbCount+1);
            } else {
                $dbCount = ($dbCount+1);
            }
echo strtoupper($dbletter[0].$comapnyID.$dbCount.$companyCount);
```

In results I am getting `AACO00302`. In this when `$dbCount` goes over 1000 entries `$dbletter` will change `AA` into `AB` and so `$dbCount` will back to `001`. After that if `$companyCount` goes over `100` then `$comapnyID` will change `CO` into `COA` and so on.

So, what I am trying to do is writing 150 lines of code into some lines. If you need any more information then please let me know.

Thanks for your time and consideration in advance.

Regards,
Qarar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer this question as I am able to get it solved. Maybe it will help you in future.

```
$companyletter = array('','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
$dbletter = array('aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah', 'ai', 'aj', 'ak', 'al', 'am', 'an', 'ao', 'ap', 'aq', 'ar', 'as', 'at', 'au', 'av', 'aw', 'ax', 'ay', 'az');

$comapnyID = mb_substr($_GET['company'], 0, 2);

$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id FROM `panel_product` WHERE `post_company` LIKE '%".$_GET['company']."%'");
$sql->execute();
$companyCount = str_pad($sql->rowCount()+1, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

$companyCountLast2 = substr($companyCount, -2); // Company Entires Count
$companyCountIndex = substr($companyCount, 0, -3); // Hundred Count


$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id FROM `panel_product`");
$sql->execute();
$dbCount = str_pad($sql->rowCount()+1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

$dbCountLast3 = substr($dbCount, -3); // DB Entires Count
$dbCountIndex = substr($dbCount, 0, -3); // Thousand Count

$sysID = strtoupper($dbletter[$dbCountIndex].$comapnyID.$companyletter[$companyCountIndex].$dbCountLast3.$companyCountLast2);
```

Thanks for your time who tries to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$companyletter = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
$dbletter = array('aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah', 'ai', 'aj', 'ak', 'al', 'am', 'an', 'ao', 'ap', 'aq', 'ar', 'as', 'at', 'au', 'av', 'aw', 'ax', 'ay', 'az');
$comapnyID = mb_substr('COMPANY', 0, 2);
$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id FROM `panel_product` WHERE `post_company` LIKE '%".$_GET['company']."%'");

$sql->execute();
$companyCount = str_pad($sql->rowCount(), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id FROM `panel_product`");
$sql->execute();
$dbCount = str_pad($sql->rowCount()+1, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo strtoupper($dbletter[0].$comapnyID.$dbCount.$companyCount);
```

p.s. Probably it's better for you to save all those data in columns of a table on your database ([foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)), then return a simple integer (row id) or a random value ([UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) to the user.

Comment: How we will add `$dbletter[x]` on every 1000 entries and `$dbletter[x]` on every 100 entries. Like I already mentioned in my question.